# How to use CSS Selector in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

Im trying to get the element of the table in my project it looks like this:

[image]

then the CSS Path is like this:

```
#gridForm > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.divtablerow > div > div.span11.leftAlign
```

My code is like this:

```
WebBrowser.Current.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gridForm > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.divtablerow > div > div.span11.leftAlign")
```

But it cant seem to locate the element.
by the way I tried using XPath still no luck.

Comment: Maybe share more of the code.. we can't give you an accurate selector unless you do

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends.. is class span11 unique? Int that case

```
WebBrowser.Current.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.span11");
```

should work.